# media container and aside inside or outside main

Tags: html, css

I want to know how to use main, aside, and media container for the following scenario. I have a header container that appears the same on all the pages and a media container that exists in all the pages but the content of the container is different. For example, in Home Page, the media container has a carousel; while in a news page, it has an image of the homepage. Should I keep the media container outside the `main` element, or should I keep it inside? If I keep it inside, the `aside` tag will also need to be inside in all the pages because from styling point of view, the sidebar will need to be extended to the side of the carousel if I put `aside` outside the main element. My current structure is like the following (Home Page):

```
<header></header>
<main role="main">
    <div class="media-container">

    </div>

    <div class="topbar">
        <!-- Widgets here-->
    </div>

    <div class="main-area">
        <!-- Main Area Widgets -->
    </div>

    <aside role="complementary">
        <!-- Sidebar Widgets -->
    </aside>
</main>
```

But I am thinking of something like the following:

```
<header></header>
<div class="media-container">

</div>

<div class="topbar">
    <!-- Widgets here-->
</div>

<main role="main">
    <!-- Main Area Widgets -->
</main>

<aside role="complementary">
    <!-- Sidebar Widgets -->
</aside>
```

In the first one, I feel like I am using `main` element as a wrapper for everything. The second one makes sense more semantically but the topbar confuses me - it will only exist in the home page. Which version makes more sense semantically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The MDN's take on `<main>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main)

> The HTML `<main>` element represents the main content of  the  of a document or application. ... This content should be unique to the document, excluding any content
>   that is repeated across a set of documents such as sidebars,
>   navigation links, copyright information, site logos, and search forms
>   (unless, of course, the document's main function is as a search form).

So by that standard, your second snippet is the better one.

Also consider using [`<header>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header) for your `topbar`.